# サーバー機でWake on Lanは機能しないのでしょうか?

Tags: network

DELLのDell EMC PowerEdge T150というハードを使用しています。
OSはWindows Server 2019をインストール済みです。

サーバー機をWake on LANで起動させることは珍しいかもしれませんが、諸事情により必要な状況です。
BIOSの設定画面にはWake on LANのEnable/Disableの設定があり、Enableにしています。
https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ja-jp/poweredge-t150/pet150_bios_ism_pub/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0-bios?guid=guid-cf672af3-f0e7-4b34-9ccc-304720ffa838&lang=ja-jp

WOLのパケットは送る側からですが、送っていることをWiresharkで確認済みです。
しかし起動しません...

万策尽きた状態のため、こちらに質問させていただきました。

何か考えられる原因がありますでしょうか。
※そもそもサーバー用途の機器(LANアダプタ)でWake on Lanは機能しない?

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、マジックパケットを送る側と問題のサーバーは同じネットワーク（サブネットが同じという意味）にいますね？

Comment: WoLができないのであれば、質問の範囲外ですがiDRACという管理機能があるようなので、こちらが使えると思います。手操作ではなく、プログラマブルにしたいとなればAPIを使うのでしょうが分かりません。https://japancatalog.dell.com/c/isg20180531/

Comment: さほどズレたコメントでは無いと思っているのですが、全く反応が無いのはしんどいですね。ほかの質問でも同様の指摘があるようですが・・・。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私自身は実際に使用したことが無く、あくまで今回調べた範囲での回答になります。

- リンク先のマニュアルには Wake on LAN に関する記載が見当たらないように見えます。
- WoL を利用するには BIOS 設定だけでなく、対応する NIC (ネットワークカード) や OS 上での設定も必要となります。Dell 製品の場合は以下リンク先も参照してみてください。

  [Dell製システムでWake On LAN（WoL）をセットアップする方法](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000175283/%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89-lan-wol-dell-%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)
- 場合によっては BIOS やネットワーク関連のドライバー更新が必要となるかもしれません。

  [PowerEdge T150のサポート | ドライバーおよびダウンロード | Dell 日本](https://www.dell.com/support/home/ja-jp/product-support/product/poweredge-t150/drivers)

Comment: cubickさん, 回答ありがとうございました。結局DELLに問い合わせしたらWakeOnLanが対応していないハードウェアということでした(先に問い合わせするべきでした)